# how to get all records greater than current date in Laravel when datatype is varchar

Tags: mysql, laravel

I am new in Laravel. I have written the query in MYSQL.
And I want that query in Laravel, can any one help?

```
SELECT * FROM `fixtures`
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(date,'%d-%m-  %Y')>=STR_TO_DATE('03-11-2016','%d-%m-%Y')
```

Column name is date whose datatype is varchar. I know its wrong DataType for date field.

Comment: TRY DATE FUNCTION FOR CONVERSION

Comment: Why not use carbon functions

Answer (score 3):

where

```
STR_TO_DATE(colname,'%m/%d/%Y) > date(now())
```

Comment: It is undefined because now() actually containts h m s too. so the format of now() is : 2014-11-22 12:45:34 , try with CURDATE() instead

Answer (score 3):

If you request or have particular date,

```
whereDate('date_column_name', '>=', $date_variable_name);
```

or

```
whereDate('date_column_name', '>=', '2016-11-02');
```

try this one.

Comment: both does not work because of datatype of column 'varchar'

Comment: the field should be in the date or timestamp.. not in the varchar.. Then it is easy to handling.. Okay i will try another answer for you.

Answer (score 2):

Check like this:

```
SELECT * FROM `fixtures`
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y-%m-%d') >= '2016-11-03'
```

or in the eloquent way:

```
\DB::table('fixtures')
    ->where(\DB::raw("DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y-%m-%d')"), '>=', '2016-11-03')
    ->get();
```

with the year - month - day way. It's better for comparison. This should works.

Answer (score 2):

Using Laravel `Eloquent` with `Carbon` :

```
q->whereDate('date ','>',Carbon::createFromFormat('d-m-Y','03-11-2016'));
```

[Carbon Document](https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon)

Answer (score 1):

Use whereRaw expression.

Eloquent syntax:

```
Fixture::whereRaw('STR_TO_DATE(date,"%d-%m-%Y") >= STR_TO_DATE("3-11-2016","%d-%m-%Y")')
```

Query Bulider Syntax:

```
DB::table('fixtures')
    ->whereRaw('STR_TO_DATE(date,"%d-%m-%Y") >= STR_TO_DATE("03-11-2016","%d-%m-%Y")');
```

Note: I assume the date would be accepted form the user, so in that case so make sure it is escaped and is in correct format. If you don't validate the user input then using raw expressions can open up possibilities for SQL Injection

Read the doc: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queries#raw-expressions

Answer (score 0):

You can use it like

```
$now_str = \Carbon\Carbon::now()->format('d-m-Y');
$q->whereDate('date', '>', $now_str);
```

You can try this as the Carbon's `now()` and `format()` method will make it work...